SvelteKitError: Not found: /undefined/get-paginated in Docker Container
I am encountering an issue with loading environment variable in my SvelteKit application when running it inside a Docker container. This question is extended from this question
The error I'm seeing is:
SvelteKitError: Not found: /undefined/get-paginated
    at resolve2 (file:///app/build/server/index.js:3850:18)
    at resolve (file:///app/build/server/index.js:3682:34)
    at Object.handle (file:///app/build/server/chunks/hooks.server-JRK4nkXw.js:31:26)
    at respond (file:///app/build/server/index.js:3680:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}

Dockerfile:
FROM node AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production

FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build build/
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules node_modules/
COPY package.json .
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD ["node", "build"]

Docker run command:
docker build -t kkawataki-frontend .  //build successfully.

docker run -p 3000:3000 \
  -e PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4000 \
 my-frontend

When I build and run the application without Docker, it works as expected. The build process is following the SvelteKit documentation on environment variables.
import { get, type Writable } from "svelte/store";
import { collectionObj } from "./store";
import { PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_URL } from "$env/static/public";

// Define the options for the fetch request
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({...}),
};

// Fetch function to get paginated posts
export const fetchPaginatedPosts = async (key: string = "posts", last_id: string = "") => {
  collectionObj.set(key);
  console.log("de: ", get(collectionObj));

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_URL}/get-paginated`,
      options
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }
    const res = await response.json();
    console.log("API call");
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};


svelte.config.js:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({ out: 'build', precompress: false, envPrefix: '', polyfill: true })
  }
};

export default config;

What could be causing the /undefined/get-paginated error in the Docker container, and how can I resolve it?

You are setting the env at runtime. Try using dynamic env: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-public.

@Dogbert I already tried it, but this will give me error on docker build: 8.424 Error: Cannot read values from $env/dynamic/public while prerendering (attempted to read env.PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_URL). Use $env/static/public instead

If you need it at compile time as well, use static and add ENV PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4000 to the Dockerfile before RUN npm run build.

Add this line before RUN npm run build
ENV YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE=http://localhost:4000

OR,
remove following line from .dockerignore:
**/.env

then add this line before RUN npm run build
COPY .env .env

